# SeriesChartType.Point all point have a square shape

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm doing a Chart with points of different color that I get of a DB with multiple colors, and all the points are different shapes. And I want points with different color. I can do the color problem, but I can't do the same shape.

Some code here

```
seriePuntos.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
seriePuntos.IsXValueIndexed = false;
seriePuntos.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
```

oh! shape that I want is a square.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try using the MarkerStyle enumerator ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
seriePuntos.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
```